# affine hull of a sum of sets

Tags: functional-analysis

Could someone, please, help me with a inclusion?I am trying to prove that:
$$Aff(A+B)=Aff(A)+Aff(B)$$, where $A,B \subset X$, $X$ a linear space;
I proved that $Aff(A+B)\subset Aff(A)+Aff(B)$,but I am having troubles in proving the reverse one;
I took $x \in Aff(A)+Aff(B)$; so, $x=a+b$, with $a \in Aff(A)$, $b \in Aff(B)$; so $a=\sum \lambda_{i}a_{i}$, $i=1,2,..n$,$\sum \lambda_{i}=1 $, $b=\sum \alpha_{i}b_{i}$,$i=1,2,..m$, with $\sum \alpha_{i}=1$;and now I dont know how cand I show that $x$ belongs to the affine hull of $A+B$; here I stucked..some help,please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $x = a+b \in \def\Aff{\mathop{\rm Aff}}\Aff(A)  +\Aff(B)$, with $a = \sum_i \lambda_i a_i$, $b = \sum_j \mu_j b_j$, $\sum_i \lambda_i = \sum_j \mu_j = 1$. We have 
\begin{align*}
  a &= \sum_i \lambda_i a_i\\
    &= \sum_i \sum_j \mu_j \lambda_i a_i
\end{align*}
due to $\sum_j \mu_j = 1$. Along the same line
$$ b = \sum_{i,j} \lambda_i \mu_j b_j $$
Hence
$$ x = a+b = \sum_{i,j} \lambda_i \mu_j(a_i + b_j) $$
And as $a_i + b_j \in A+ B$ and $\sum_{i,j} \lambda_i \mu_j = 1$, we have $x \in \Aff(A+B)$.